# oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I moved my PHP + Oracle to a new server running Linux (previous Server ran Sun).

Now I get following error:

```
Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories in /opt/m/app/zerfa/test3.php on line 7

Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-01804: failure to initialize timezone information in     /opt/m/app/zerfa/test3.php on line 7
Connection Failed: /u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2/lib ---     /u00/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_2
```

the code which has created this is:

```
<?
$test = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')." --- ".getenv('ORACLE_HOME');
$this2 = oci_connect("m1","m1", "DMX16") or die("<b>Connection Failed: $test </b>").oci_error();
$conn = OCILogon( "m1", "m1", "DMX16") or die;

$stmt = ocipars($conn, "SELECT * FROM ibresa") or die;

ociexecute($stmt);

echo "<HTML><PRE>";

while (ocifetch($stmt)) {
print "\n";
$ncols = ocinumcols($stmt);
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++ ) {
$column_name = ocicolumnname($stmt,$i);
$column_value = ociresult($stmt,$i);
print $column_name . ': ' . $column_value . "\n";
}
print "\n";
}
ocifreestatement($stmt);
ocilogoff($conn);

echo "</PRE></HTML>\n";

ocilogoff($handle);

?>
```

Comment: Screenshots from my phpinfo()
    http://i57.tinypic.com/24nr9ro.png
    http://i61.tinypic.com/2ihtk6q.png

Comment: I hope oracle extension loaded?,search for oracle instance/extension in phpinfo()

Comment: Yes I configured it properly I believe: http://i57.tinypic.com/25uqv5u.png